# Ruby Copy-on-Write: Why MRI Ruby string has a shared pointer to one string

Tags: ruby, string, pointers

I'm reading internal Ruby about how Ruby handles with string when copy.

```
str = "StackOverFlow"
ustr2 = str.dup
```

here is the image for JRuby when ustr2 is duplicated from str:

[image]

I can understand this. But below is the image of MRI Ruby interpreter:

[image]

The thing I don't know is: why both String should have shared pointer to another pointer points to that string. I think we only need pointer point to head of string. (In this case is character 'G').

Thanks

@Edit: This concept and those 2 illustrations I got from "Ruby under the Microscope" book.

Comment: It might be helpful, and certainly fair, to write that the diagrams are from the book "Ruby under a microscope" by Pat Shaughnessy. Does the book not offer the answer to your question, it is very detailed?

Comment: @MladenJablanović  Yes, I get from book "Ruby under a microscope". Just because I don't think that information will be helpful :D I will attach to my post. In book, author doesn't explain this point.

Comment: And the book is very detailed. Maybe this point is really trivial :(